# User_properties column is coming back as null in bigquery after export from GA4

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-firebase, demographics

I have a problem with a specific column in GA4-Bigquery. The **User_properties** column is coming in as **null** and I would like to get the demographic information including **age and gender** in **bigquery**.

Doing some preliminary research, I've already verified that `google signals enabled` in the admin console **is enabled**.

Are there any additional configuration settings, steps or information needed to get data in this column?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately data from Google signals is not exported to BigQuery. To quote the documentation directly, “Google Analytics 4 exports event data associated with anonymous cookies to BigQuery”.
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9383630